# Como funciona a suspensão de usuários?

Tags: suporte, suspensão

Notei recentemente muita gente reclamando de tal pessoa que não vou citar o nome. Entrei no perfil dele e percebi que ele havia apenas **1 ponto de reputação** e uma mensagem em vermelho dizendo que a conta foi suspensa por um tempo para *tranquilizar*.

E as perguntas que tenho a respeito disso são as seguintes:

- O que leva uma pessoa a ficar suspensa?
- Existem "Tiers" de suspensão? Se sim, quais suas punições?
- Afinal, o que a suspensão traz de benefício à comunidade?
- E o que a suspensão está *tranquilizando*?

Afinal, como **bônus na pergunta**, é possível fazer um voto democrático para suspender alguém?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> O que leva uma pessoa a ficar suspensa?

São muitos fatores, mas quando está indicando "para tranquilizar" é por causa de mau comportamento. É o caso da pessoa repetidas vezes não seguir as regras, especialmente o [be nice].

> Existem "Tiers" de suspensão? Se sim, quais suas punições?

De forma forma geral, sim, mas não é uma regra formal, depende da gravidade, de quanto a pessoa faz, da percepção de que ela está fazendo por ser "sem noção" ou de propósito, se está tentando melhorar. Pode ser 1 dias, 7 dias, 30 dias, 1 ano, definitivo.

> Afinal, o que a suspensão traz de benefício à comunidade?

Eu nem gosto de ver isto como punição, mas sim como forma de segregar alguém que está causando problema e demonstra que consegue conviver com os demais. Ela até pode ser uma sinalização para a pessoa que ela precisar repensar seu comportamento. Então parece ser efetivo. Se alguém quiser discordar e dar alternativas reais e efetivas é só postar.

> E o que a suspensão está tranquilizando?

A pessoa, a comunidade.

> Afinal, como bônus na pergunta, é possível fazer um voto democrático para suspender alguém?

De forma geral não é possível. É comum que os moderadores discutem antes de rolar uma suspensão, mas não entre a comunidade. É algo até para se pensar. Eu sou favorável à comunidade participar mais pelo menos para iniciar o processo. A decisão final ser democrática é um pouco complicado. Democracia direta só pode ser aplicada quando todo mundo é muito ciente de tudo o que se passa, e todos possuem ampla capacidade de abstração, o que não acontece.

Comment: Maniero eu estou de acordo com você, mas essa última frase me faz alguma comichão. Democracia direta pode ser aplicada sempre, seja todo mundo ciente de tudo o que se passa ou não. O julgamento em modo de democracia é que não.

Comment: Você pode discordar disso, mas comunismo tem mais chance e dar certo que isso, se fosse real, já teria sido aplicado em algum lugar com sucesso. Bom, estritamente, pode ser aplicada, mas com consequências desastrosas tão grandes que as pessoas vão preferir até uma ditadura logo em seguida.

Comment: Para além disso, os moderadores têm acesso a informação sobre o que se passa que os utilizadores normais não têm — logo, os últimos nunca poderiam tomar uma decisão informada sobre a situação.